# What size for a dictionary is too big for an app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am writing a Windows Phone app (in c#), and it has a lot of data in it.

I would like to store this data in a dictionary (or less ideally an array), but there will be about 10 000 dictionary values (spread out across 3-4 dictionaries). Do you think these dictionaries would be too big, and take up too much memory?

The dictionaries will be `Dictionary<int, customClass>`

It would obviously be better to use an array, but do you think it is ok to use a dictionary?

Comment: I think the easiest way to find out is to implement the app and see if you run into any performance problems.

Comment: Mmm. True, I guess I could just try it :)

Comment: :) On a serious note, it does depend on a variety of things. If you know beforehand all the models of Windows Phone that your app will run on (maybe it's an app internal to a company?) then this will make your life easier since you can just design for that phone. If it's *all* Windows phones, then you need to design for the lowest-end model that you want to support.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know nothing about Windows phones and their memory limits, so maybe someone else can provide more helpful advice. But generally with performance questions, my answer is: try it

Comment: Ya, definitely has to work on all phone.

Comment: You should not use more when 90 MB of memory when write WP applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of items in a collection like dictionary/array/list doesn't matter very much, 10w integers cost less than 1M(about 100,000 * 4bytes). So the memory cost mainly depends on what stores in your `CustomClass`. If the class contains a few primitive properties only, it won't cost very much memory either. You shouldn't worry about the memory cost very much, unless you do something like loading a file's data into on property of the class.

Comment: 4/6 of the classes are just ints, strings, bools. The other 2 have lists inside them...

Comment: @Toadums: Then the size of the dictionary mainly depends on the items of the lists.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the number of actual objects you are storing... and the size of those objects. The dictionaries themselves will be only 32 (or 64) bits x 10,000 x 2 (key and value) plus a small overhead - ie small... because the dictionaries only store a pointer to your object.